# P-channel MOSFET switch is broken in high voltage

Tags: mosfet, circuit-analysis, mosfet-driver, p-channel

i want to use a mosfet switch 30V voltage

[image]

[image]

the motor operates when the temperature is high

before this circuit i changed R9, R10
R9 -> 4K7
R10 -> 680
and MOSFET was broken

so i changed R9, R10 like this circuit

This circuit works but Q4(P-channel mosfet)'s Vgs is up to 28V when Q2 off

in datasheet Q4's MAX Vgss is 25V

i want only ON/OFF, not PWM. Is there anything that needs to be corrected?

[Edit]this is the simulation of my circuit

[image]

[image]

i'm running a physical circuit right now (PCB)
the FET temperature is about 40'C
(i changed D5(15V) -> 12V zener)
this circuit works, But I don't know if this circuit is safe.

Comment: When Q2 is OFF, VGS of Q4 becomes 0V. So, I am surprised that you measure 28V. Terminal 1 is the source of Q4. Hope you are not referring to VGD

Comment: If zener diode D5 is actually a 15V part, and connected as shown from gate to source, it should never approach 28V. But you need a MOSFET with Vdss much higher than 30V for safety margin.

Comment: @sai, i added picture,

Comment: @PStechPaul, i chaged zener 12V

Comment: @KimJiHoon, clearly, from your picture, for the case where Q1 is OFF, Q2 gate and source are at 30V. So, VGS = 0V. So, there is no VGS issue

Comment: I suspect miswiring or bad component. Can you show an image of your actual circuit?

Comment: @PStechPaul, Oh It was my fault
What I was testing now was open because the MOSFET was broken
R1 was 2R2 that's why my FET was broken, I replaced R1 with 2K2 and it works fine.

Comment: Your symbol for the LM393 does not look right. Inverting input pin 2 is shown as an output. Output pin 3 is shown as an input.

Comment: @PStechPaul, I reversed it for the inverted output Can I use it like this?

Comment: The pin numbers seem OK, but it's a dual comparator. It must be OK if it's working correctly for you - just the symbol doesn't match the pins. https://www.elprocus.com/lm393-ic-pin-configuration-circuit-diagram-and-its-working/

Comment: @PStechPaul, yes LM393 circuit is being tested on the breadboard I will create a new LM393 library when I make it with PCB, thank you so much!